# Combining two sentences

Tags: ruby

I have `survey.rb` with some questions.

```
puts "Let's take a survey."
puts "Who is your mom?"
mom = gets.chomp
puts "Hello, I am "
print mom
print"."
```

When I run it, the result is:

```
Let's take a survey.
Who is your mom?
EAD (for example)
Hello, I am
EAD.
```

How do I combine the `'Hello, I am'` and `'EAD'` together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options. You can replace the `puts` for `"hello, I am "` with print:

```
print "Hello, I am "
print mom
puts "."
```

Or use string interpolation:

```
puts "Hello, I am #{mom}."
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do it with 2 prints like

```
     print 'Hello, I am'
     print mom
     puts '.'
```

?